# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized. What's going on?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I'm testing my new plugin an exception keeps getting thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized! Please help! Here's the code:

```
package me.plugin.example;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;    


public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Main(), this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
        event.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + p.getPlayerListName() +  " has joined the game.");
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Welcome to the server!");
        p.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("example")) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BOLD + ""+ ChatColor.ITALIC + "Hello! Hope you like to be set on fire. lol :P");
        player.setFireTicks(20);
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onDisable() {

}
```

}
I know that you're only supposed to declare one JavaPlugin class per plugin, which I think I'm doing. But it keeps saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:122) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at me.plugin.example.Main.<init>(Main.java:19) ~[?:?]
        at me.plugin.example.Main.onEnable(Main.java:27) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:414) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:378) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:333) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:263) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:125) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at me.plugin.example.Main.<init>(Main.java:19) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:292) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        ... 2 more
```

I really need to test this plugin to see if it works, and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the `onEnable` you’re already in a class instance of the class, don’t instantiate a new instance, just pass the `this` pointer.

Comment: @vandench Thank you for pointing the error out! Really helped out and my plugin works now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace clearly tells where is the problem. [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
...
at me.plugin.example.Main.<init>(Main.java:19) ~[?:?]
```

Your code:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Main(), this);
} //<-- 19th line
```

And the problem is when you register your event you are creating a new instance of your `Main` class. So replace `new Main()`

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Main(), this);
```

with `this`

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you to put your event handler in a separate class.

Try removing the below line

```java
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Main(), this);
```

and please don't ask your question several times.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It really helped out the plugin. Apologies for spamming the same question. :P

Answer (score 0):

`PluginAlreadyInitialized` error occours when the .jar file contains more than one subclass of JavaPlugin class. Use the JavaPlugin class only once in all plugins from.

Comment: From what I see, I only have one subclass in my plugin. And the subclass "Main" is the only class to use the JavaPlugin. So to me, I don't understand what you're trying to say. :/

Comment: @MoMoMeer if you have 2 plugins with the same link to the main class (Like 1 plugin being 'com.rb2750.Main' and the other being the same) it will cause this problem. It is probably better if you have a separate package for each plugin like 'com.rb2750.PLUGIN.Main'

Comment: I have renamed my package to "me.momomeer.eventexample", and I still keep getting the same error? What's going on?